# Inserting an array into a child collection in MongoDB is omitting the _t Discriminator

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface IChild { }

public class Child : IChild { }
```

Inserting the Children property as an array like this:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("Test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Parent>("Parent");
            collection.InsertOne(new Parent { Children = new[] { new Child() } });
        }
    }
}
```

The _t Discriminator is missing in the DB:

```
{
    "_id":"5bf6aef6c0beccc414b70d45",
    "Child":[{}]
}
```

If I use a List instead:

```
collection.InsertOne(new Parent { Children = new List<IChild> { new Child() } });
```

The _t Discriminator is set correctly:

```
{
    "_id":"5bf6b074c0beccc414b70dc2",
    "Children":[{"_t":"Child"}]
}
```

This seems like a bug or at the very least a very unintuitive behavior.

Additional information:
The behavior is a problem because the missing _t Discriminator is causing an Exception when deserializing the object:

> System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the Children property of class TestConsoleApp.Parent: Unable to determine actual type of object to deserialize for interface type TestConsoleApp.IChild.'

Comment: if it works for the list, then why use an array? You can always call `ToList()` extension on array to get working list

Comment: sure, but that's easy to forget. I would like to prevent programming errors like that. I could just change the property type from IEnumerable to List but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: At the first look the type of the array element (`Child[]`) is different from the type of the list element (`List<IChild>`). I would assume that if you use `new IChild[] { new Child() },` the array code will work. And if you use `new List<Child> { new Child() } `, the list code will stop working.

Comment: `new IChild[] { new Child() }` does not work

Comment: When it comes to collections in DTOs, I always avoid using interfaces and use concrete implementations. It seems that it avoids a host of problems, for whatever the reason. I think it is due to the fact that interfaces are too abstract to expect consistent development philosophies and treatment across different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused because there is no implementation class of IChild interface discovered by mongo. In other words mongo driver does not know that IChild implementation must be created using Child class. Thats why it is adding _t Discriminator.

To solve the issue you can specify implied serialization.

```
public class Parent
{
[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<IEnumerable<IChild>, IEnumerable<Child>>))]
    public IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}
```

With this attribute it will not create _t Discrimination but will use Child class for deserializing.

In case if you want to force discriminator on dynamic instances you can use

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
    public class Child : IChild { }
```

Note that this header should be added to all classes for which you need to force discriminator creation.

Comment: I want the _t Discriminator to be created though, because I have multiple implementations of IChild.

Comment: If you want to force discriminator creation on dynamic instances you can add the header to your class instance
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
    public class Child : IChild { }
Just edited answer

Comment: That actually worked. Pretty inconvenient but it's a decent workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's a bug as you said, actually considering the exception you mentioned its probably a bug. 
Anyway, this is the GitHub repository of the project https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver.

In the  README.md you can find instructions about how you report a bug (Please tell me if you are not going to report it so I'll do so).

In the meantime, I think the best solution will be replacing the `IEnumerable<IChild>` with `IList<IChild>` to prevent other programmers from inserting data the wrong way.

Edit: Please check if IList Solves the problem because this line is compiling (at least for me)

```
    public static IList<int> Ints { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ints = new[] {1,2,3,4};
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
```

If it does not solve your problem I would have just used `List<IChild>`. It's not pretty but it will work.

Comment: `IList` is not helping since, as you've mentioned, an array is also an `IList`. I'm gonna use `List` as a workaround. I'm not gonna report the bug because I don't want to create an account with their Jira system right now. Feel free to do so, though.

Comment: No problem i will :)

Comment: Did you post the bugreport? If so, could you link it?

Comment: To be honest i forgot but i did it now. The link is above.